# Can't Add Tag to Question

Tags: support, tags

When I first posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35385359/binding-indexer) question, I added the [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp) tag to it. However, several minutes later, I noticed that the tag wasn't there. So I edited and added it... and it disappeared again. When I hit "Save" it doesn't give any errors or anything, the tag simply isn't added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp) is a [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/win-universal-app/synonyms) of [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app). Hence you cannot add the tag to the question.

See the question [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work) for more details.

> Editing a question tagged with a synonym tag causes it to be replaced by the master tag.