# Inform user when a tag is removed because it is a synonym

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonym-process

I got confused by synonymous tag removal when attempting to add the [listview tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/listview/info) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25147107/145173), which had the "android-listview" tag. I didn't know what was going on until I found [a meta post on the topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316801/145173).

A message saying that "android-listview" was removed and why would have been very helpful. This suggestion is to notify a user attempting to add a synonymous tag, that the tag will not be preserved and why.

Comment: That would very quickly get irritating.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I doubt most people are in the habit of doing this frequently enough for it to become irritating. Especially if they learn from previous messages. It just needs to be a non modal info message that doesn't interrupt the flow of what they are doing.

Comment: @MartinSmith *shrug* twice would annoy me. It's probably too much dev work to only show the message the first time it is needed.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I'm not proposing that it is only shown the first time. Why would you be in the habit of frequently editing in tags to a question that is already tagged with one of its synonyms (and so gets silently dropped)? It's a complete waste of your time. This would alert you to that.

Comment: @MartinSmith You seem to have ignored the most common use case - someone asks a question and tries to tag it with a synonym ... I entered "flag" for the tag and it got changed to "flagging", why? (an example of a synonym jusy created on meta.su)

Comment: @DavidPostill - I'm not interpreting this question as being about that case (maybe incorrectly)

Comment: @Edward  Can you please clarify the feature request per the above?

Comment: I was asking about the case where you enter two synonymous tags (e.g. "listview" and "android-listview"), and SO automatically removes one of them ("android-listview"). I don't know what happens if you only enter a synonym (e.g. "android-listview"). Does SO change it to the canonical tag ("listview")? If so, I'd suggest that the user be notified of that event as well. The cases of tag removal and modification are distinct but related.

Comment: @Edward That would actually be a better suggestion. What really happens is that the synonym is rewritten to its master tag. Notifying a user better that a tag is a synonym and will be replaced is a better feature because it covers both cases. In your case the tag gets "removed" because after rewritten you have two of the same tag, which isn't necessary. We don't really need a separate notification of removal, just notification of the synonym change is enough.